# Scan a QRCode into a browser with phone's username to log people that scanned the QRcode

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

Is it possible to pass the phone's username or email when reading a qrcode from a phone? I am developing a game that will collect points when people scan qrcodes in different places and therefore I need to assign points to each person if he/she finds and scans the qrcodes along the path.

Comment: If the users scan the code with your app, then why not? If they scan the code with any app that just redirects to the URL from the code, then no.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. A QR-Code is a static Path (URL, ...), you can't add User Specific Parameters.

Probably over your App, after they Scan, add there specific User Parameters to the URL and your Web-Service simply read them.

Answer (score 0):

If the QR code does contain this info, you're done. :)

If not, the user info has to be added somewhere, best located inside your app that starts the QR scanner as a sub process, then adds the user info, and then reports back to your server.